# Set Data Access Mode property to: Table or View- fast load

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am creating a I have a dynamic SSIS package using VB.NET (rather than using BIDS). block of VB.NET code, which creates an SSIS OLEDB data destination:

```
Dim destComponent As IDTSComponentMetaData100 = pipeline.ComponentMetaDataCollection.[New]()
        destComponent.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OleDbDestination"
        destComponent.ValidateExternalMetadata = True

        Dim destDesignTimeComponent As IDTSDesigntimeComponent100 = destComponent.Instantiate()
        destDesignTimeComponent.ProvideComponentProperties()
        destComponent.Name = "OleDb Destination"

        destDesignTimeComponent.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 3)
        destDesignTimeComponent.SetComponentProperty("OpenRowset", strDestinationTableName) 'Dts.Variables("DatasetName").Value)
```

In BIDS there is a property called: Data Access Mode, which can have a value of: Table or View- fast load.  How do I set this in VB.NET?

Comment: the value of 3 corresponds to AM_OPENROWSET_FASTLOAD. So, it looks like you're doing that. What happens when you view the resultant package? The code in EzAPI does what you're doing `m_comp.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", value.GetHashCode()); ReinitializeMetaData();` for setting the access mode

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, [EzAPI](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/21238) might be of interest. It's an SSIS wrapper library created the SSIS team for testing purposes. I used it for a while to programmatically generate my packages but ultimately, found it lacking as a general purpose ETL abstractor

Comment: @Blinkc thanks.  When I run the package it appears to execute in batches of 9000.  It takes about 12 minutes to transfer 40,000 records from one table to another.  It is instant when I run the package in BIDS.